# I get weird vectors in Maya

Tags: 3d, polygon, modeling, mesh, maya

He.. I'm kindda new to maya and i try to learn something out of it. I only got a problem. I try to model a face. But some vector/faces are really ugly when i smooth them ( the dark grey surfaces).Does anyone now what te problem is? And of i can fix this?

[image: Normal]

[image: Normal + edges]

[image: Smooth]

[image: Smooth + edges]

Comment: This doesn't look very programming-related. Maybe try at [graphicdesign.se]?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely either of two things:

1. Your normals are pointing to the backside. To fix this, select the faces with a hard edge and go to the Polygons window menu, **Normals -> Reverse**.
2. You have hard edge. Select the faces, edges or the whole object and go to the Polygons window menu, **Normals -> Soften Edge**.